# RSA Public key-Prove that if any one of p,q,ϕ(n) is known, then you can quickly use it to find the other two as well.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I'm a little confused as to how to go about this, I've read through the bottom answer to this question : [RSA solving for $p$ and $q$ knowing $\phi(pq)$ and $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279478/rsa-solving-for-p-and-q-knowing-phipq-and-n?rq=1) but in that question they find p and q after knowing phi(n) AND n. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Everyone is supposed to know $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $p$:

- $q=\frac{n}{p}$
- $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$

---

Given $q$:

- $p=\frac{n}{q}$
- $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$

---

Given $\phi(n)$:

- $p=\frac{(n-\phi(n)+1)+\sqrt{(n-\phi(n)+1)^2-4n}}{2}$
- $q=\frac{n}{p}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at the two easy cases. If you know either $p$ or $q$, then finding the other two are very easy given that $pq =n$ and $n$ is publicly known.

Given that you know $\phi(n)$, then the answer provided in the link you gave is a really clever way of finding $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I don't think I had fully understood that n and e are publicly known.